# Get result from two promises in Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I have the next function in my WebApp with Firebase:

```
function loadMonthData(){
    let ganancias = 0;
    let perdidas  = 0;
    let thisMonth = new Date();

    thisMonth.setHours(0);
    thisMonth.setMinutes(0);
    thisMonth.setMilliseconds(0);
    thisMonth.setDate(1);

    fireIngresos.orderByChild('timestamp')
        .startAt(thisMonth.getTime())
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot)=>{
            snapshot.forEach((ingreso)=>{
                ganancias += ingreso.val().cash;
            });
        });

    fireGastos.orderByChild('timestamp')
        .startAt(thisMonth.getTime())
        .once('value')
        .then((snapshot)=>{
            snapshot.forEach((perdida)=>{
                perdidas += perdida.val().cash;
            });
        });

    return ganancias - perdidas;
}
```

This get the sum of the property `cash` of all elements in my references fireIngresos and FireGastos (from the beginning of the month), then this return the difference of the two results.

The problem (evidently) is the promises ¿How can I do this correctly?

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: @guest271314 ¿the difference of the two results?

Comment: See updated post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `async/await`, `return` a value from `.then()`

```
async function loadMonthData(){

    let ganancias = 0;
    let perdidas  = 0;
    let thisMonth = new Date();

    thisMonth.setHours(0);
    thisMonth.setMinutes(0);
    thisMonth.setMilliseconds(0);
    thisMonth.setDate(1);

    return await fireIngresos.orderByChild('timestamp')
           .startAt(thisMonth.getTime())
           .once('value')
           .then(snapshot => {
             snapshot.forEach(ingreso => {
               ganancias += ingreso.val().cash;
             });
             return ganacias
           }) 
         - await fireGastos.orderByChild('timestamp')
           .startAt(thisMonth.getTime())
           .once('value')
           .then(snapshot => {
             snapshot.forEach(perdida => {
               perdidas += perdida.val().cash
             });
             return peridadas
           });

}

loadMonthData().then(result => {// do stuff with result});
```

```js
function promise(n) {
  return new Promise(resolve => 
           setTimeout(resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000), n)
         ).then(data => data)
}

async function diff() {
  return await promise(2 * 4) - await promise(2 * 2);
}

diff().then(res => console.log(res)); // 4
```

Comment: FYI [`snapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) isn't an array.

Comment: @Phil Have not tried firebase. What needs to be adjusted to get result OP expects?

Comment: You can't use `reduce`. You're stuck with `forEach` unfortunately

Comment: works ! but some vars have wrong names like 'peridadas' (is perdidas)

Comment: @CristoferFuentes What do perdidas and ganancias mean?

Comment: @guest271314 ganancias is profit and perdidas is losses in Spanish :P